# Python ~ Replace a character in a string with a string list item

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I need to individually replace **each** character in a string with a list of single character strings.

I have a list and a string variable

```
charList = ['a','e','i','o','u']
string = 'str'
```

And I need the output to be this

> **a**tr, **e**tr, **i**tr, **o**tr, **u**tr, s**a**r, s**e**r, s**i**r, s**o**r, s**u**r, st**a**, st**e**, st**i**, st**o**, st**u**

While the string variable may be as long as a 30 letter word.

Can I do this in python?

It would be better if looped someway that each iteration could be later checked with another variable for some condition. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Tell us what have you done so far!

Comment: I'm a noob and I just learnt a while ago that strings are immutable so I tried making a list out of the string variable, tried using for loop to change replace one list's item with other one's and to join the list to make it string again, but couldn't make it work. Thank you very much for this guys. Thanks for the advice Lauro, i changed the name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code:**

```
list = ['a','e','i','o','u']
string = 'str'
out = [string[:i] + c + string[i + 1:] for i in range(len(string)) for c in list]
```

**Output:**

```
['atr', 'etr', 'itr', 'otr', 'utr', 'sar', 'ser', 'sir', 'sor', 'sur', 'sta', 'ste', 'sti', 'sto', 'stu']
```

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick:

```
solution = []
for index, _ in enumerate(string):
    for letter in list:
        solution.append(string[:index] + letter + string[(index+1):])
print(solution)
```

I advice to change the variable name of 'list' since that's a keyword in Python.

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 1):

```
old_list = ['a','e','i','o','u']
string = 'str'

new_list = []
for ind,char in enumerate(string):
    new_list += [string[:ind] + string[ind:].replace(char, i, 1) for i in old_list]

print(new_list)
```

output:

```
['atr', 'etr', 'itr', 'otr', 'utr', 'sar', 'ser', 'sir', 'sor', 'sur', 'sta', 'ste', 'sti', 'sto', 'stu']
```

Comment: It will not work with string with duplicate letters

Answer (score -1):

```
def replace_char_for_list(astring, char, mylist):
    return [astring.replace(char, new_char) for new_char in mylist]

replace_char_for_list('str', 's', ['a','e','i','o','u'])
#['atr', 'etr', 'itr', 'otr', 'utr']
```

Comment: It will not work with string with duplicate letters

Comment: OP wants to replace **all** the characters in the string, not only the first one.

Comment: yes @VishnuDasu is right, please read the question before commenting

Comment: I need to individually replace each character in a string with a list of single character strings.

Comment: Your code replaces only `s` with `['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']`. OP would like to replace `t`and `r` as well.

Comment: my code replaces whatever you pass as char to replace_char_for_list, he can iterate the list of replacements

Comment: Yes he sure can but it would be great if you could make your answer complete by editing your code or telling OP to iterate through all characters.

Comment: That would be great, I agree